# Oracle PL/SQL get the first letter from the name(HUN)

Tags: oracle, plsql, alphabet

The question sounds easy because only need a `substring (name,1,1)`. But in the Hungarian language there are many letter wich contains multicharacter. eg : `CS,DZ,DZS,LY,NY,SZ,TY,ZS`

```
  IF v_type='by_name' THEN  
    select DISTINCT name
      into v_result
    from my_table
    where instr(_START_LETTERS_,substr(upper(v_name),1,1))>0 and ZIPCODE = v_act_zipcode;
    return v_result;
```

and my table eg:

```
zipcode name  _START_LETTERS
1234   Ryan    A,B,C
1234   Bryan   CS,D
```

And if i want to get my name CSanád i need to get CS not the first char C-> becuase i will get multirow exception.

Do you have anysuggestion to use get the first lettor? Or I have to write a huge if-else/case structure to make my code awful and impenetrable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most straight-forward solution is to write a stored function that extracts the first letter:

```
create function hun_first_letter(name in varchar2) return varchar2 as
begin
  if substr(upper(name),1,3) in ('DZS') then
    return substr(name,1,3);
  elsif substr(upper(name),1,2) in ('CS','DZ','LY','NY','SZ','TY','ZS','GY') then
    return substr(name,1,2);
  else
    return substr(name,1,1);
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: FYI i forget to add 'GY' :P if somebody want to use properly add the 'GY' to the second if!

Comment: @Csanesz: Thanks for the info, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `substr(upper(v_name), 1, 1)` with:

```
regexp_substr(upper(v_name), '^[[:alpha:][.cs.][.xx.][.yy.]]', 1, 1, 'i')
```

where
`[:alpha:]` is a special function (any letter) - actually, I don't know, maybe this function alone can find collating sequences (depending on NLS)

`[.cs.]` is an example of a collating sequence;
`[.xx.], [.yy.]` - other collating sequences possible in your NLS

So the **regexp_substr** above tries to find any letter OR 'cs' OR 'xx' OR 'yy' and etc.
It starts searching from position = 1 and returns occurance = 1. Finally, the search is case insentitive (**'i'**)

But first of all you may check whether this function:

```
regexp_substr(upper(v_name), '^[[:alpha:]]', 1, 1, 'i')
```

would find your collating sequences (I'd be glad to know this)

Comment: thanks  I wanted to use regexp. but this alpha give me error at oracle. So I cant use it now. So i think i will you the function that ammmoQ wrote it works perfectly.